# Javascript -add onlick within a function

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

I have encountered a slight difficulty within my code. Following function is involved in a part of a small game for private use. My question is, how can add a sound if the image generated is clicked on?

Code:

```
function img1() {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "img1.png";
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    img.className = "img1";
}
```

I'd like this soundfunction to be triggered on click:

```
function sound1() {
    var audio = new Audio('s1.wav');
    audio.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the click event to the image

```
function img1() {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "img1.png";
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    img.className = "img1";
    img.addEventListener( "click", sound1, false ); //this line has been added
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked out perfectly. I will make sure to rate your comment as helpful!

Comment: @Eppes sure, glad to help